# Firebase A/B Testing - Very High Total Revenue and Revenue Per User Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing, abtest

I conducted numerous A/B tests using Firebase Remote Config, and the results I obtained showed that the total revenue and revenue per user data were much higher than expected. The number of included users seems accurate, and our revenue data in Firebase Analytics also appears to be correct. Can you help with this?

I checked my Firebase setup and events and everything is working properly,

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/_QNZ2ce_mLM